# convert composition of date-time column in sqlite3 db?

Tags: sqlite, datetime

In Node.js I created a DATETIME string for in my sqlite3 database using moment.js and I formatted it

```
moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD h:mm:ss')
```

Never needed that column until after this project and I want to do some calculations. Turns out I should have formatted using 'hh', or two decimals for the hour (eg. '09' instead of '9') because sqlite3 otherwise won't see it as a valid DATETIME entry. Now I have 20k entries with a tonload of invalid DATETIME entries, argh!

What would be an efficient way to update all the entries in this column to valid sqlite3 DATETIME entries? Is it possible through just SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may work:

```
UPDATE t SET d = SUBSTR(d,1,11) || '0' || SUBSTR(d,12) WHERE LENGTH(d) = 18;
```